# Animating CAShapeLayer's strokeColor with CABasicAnimation

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation, cashapelayer

I've been unsuccessful at animating a flashing stroke on a `CAShapeLayer` using the answer from [this previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080952/using-core-animation-to-animate-strokecolor) thread, and after many searches I can find no other examples of animating the stroke using `CABasicAnimation`.

What I want to do is have the stroke of my `CAShapeLayer` pulse between two colors.  Using `CABasicAnimation` for opacity works fine, but the `[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeColor"]` eludes me, and I'd appreciate any advice on how to successfully implement.

```
    CABasicAnimation *strokeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeColor"];
    strokeAnim.fromValue         = (id) [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    strokeAnim.toValue           = (id) [UIColor purpleColor].CGColor;
    strokeAnim.duration          = 1.0;
    strokeAnim.repeatCount       = 0.0;
    strokeAnim.autoreverses      = NO;
    [shapeLayer addAnimation:strokeAnim forKey:@"animateStrokeColor"];

//    CABasicAnimation *opacityAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
//    opacityAnimation.fromValue         = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
//    opacityAnimation.toValue           = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
//    opacityAnimation.duration          = 1.0;
//    opacityAnimation.repeatCount       = 0.0;
//    opacityAnimation.autoreverses      = NO;
//    [shapeLayer addAnimation:opacityAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

Uncommenting the opacity animation results in an expected opacity fade.  The stroke animation produces no effect.  An implicit strokeColor change animates as expected, but I would like documented confirmation that strokeColor can be explicitly animated using CABasicAnimation.

Update: The specific problem was that shapeLayer.path was NULL.  Correcting that fixed the problem.

Comment: Eludes you... how? What have you tried? How is it not working? What happens instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code below works great for me. What is the lineWidth of your shapeLayer stroke path? Could that be the issue?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBezierPath * circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.view.bounds];

    CAShapeLayer * shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = circle.CGPath;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor =[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    [shapeLayer setLineWidth:15.0];

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

    CABasicAnimation *strokeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeColor"];
    strokeAnim.fromValue         = (id) [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    strokeAnim.toValue           = (id) [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    strokeAnim.duration          = 3.0;
    strokeAnim.repeatCount       = 0;
    strokeAnim.autoreverses      = YES;
    [shapeLayer addAnimation:strokeAnim forKey:@"animateStrokeColor"];

}
```

Let me know if it works for you...

Comment: Thank you, that confirms that strokeColor can be animated with CABasicAnimation.  My problem must lie elsewhere (I suspect either in the previous rendering of the path or in the subsequent rendering in drawLayer: inContext).  I will update for future reference when I discover the exact cause.

Comment: Do update the thread with your findings! I would love to know what was the issue.