# Cannot animate CALayer strokeColor

Tags: ios, calayer

I've been trying to draw a simple rectangle and animate the edge color. I tried using the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080952/using-core-animation-to-animate-strokecolor) link and it still doesn't help. I finally fixed it by changing the layer's border color and animating the same. That worked fine.

Is there a KVO for `strokeColor` because I'm getting it working for the `backgroundColor` of layer.

I'm on XCode 4.6 running iOS SDK 6.1

This is what I've been doing:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

CABasicAnimation *strokeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeColor"];
strokeAnim.fromValue         = (id) [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
strokeAnim.toValue           = (id) [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
strokeAnim.duration          = 3.0;
strokeAnim.repeatCount       = 0;
strokeAnim.autoreverses      = YES;
[self.layer addAnimation:strokeAnim forKey:@"animateStrokeColor"];

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, squareLength, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, squareLength, squareLength);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, squareLength);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, 0);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: Wait, are you adding an animation inside drawRect? 

Answer (score 0):

After researching this same question, I found out that `strokeColor` is not an animatable property on a `CALayer`.  I *think* this has something to do with CALayer getting rendered to a cached bitmap.

The solution is to use a `CAShapeLayer` instead where `strokeColor` ***is*** animatable.

Comment: "...strokeColor is not an animatable property on a CALayer..." is misleading. It's not that it's not animatable on CALayer. It's that the property doesn't even exist on CALayer.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's because CALayer gets rendered to a bitmap? I'd love to see some reference for that statement.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist - I'm certainly no CA expert - so happy to proved wrong.  Am going by what I read in "iOS Core Animation: Advanced Techniques" By Nick Lockwood - page in question: [CAShapeLayer](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=QfhdAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT109&lpg=PT109&dq=cashapelayer+vector+based&source=bl&ots=O6vPC8p465&sig=4cyMaQQKyS73dt4PGufAhlYhCCY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7D5jUvLwIO6PiAfI-oC4DA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=cashapelayer%20vector%20based&f=false)

Comment: I'm sorry. I was probably too vague in that comment. What I meant was: are you sure that the reason that CALayer doesn't have a strokeColor property has something to do with it being rendered into a cached bitmap. Would that also mean that CAShapeLayer does not have a cached bitmap because it has a strokeColor property? It is correct that there is caching behind the scenes but that is an implementation detail in this case and I don't think it's any different between CALayer and its subclasses. It all comes down to naming. …

Comment: … Paths are stroked so shape layers have properties to configure the stroke but a regular layer is always a rectangle so it has border properties instead because that name makes more sense in the context of a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr;** You probably meant `@"borderColor"`

---

Unless you did override `+ (Class)layerClass` in your view (which I doubt that you did) your view's layer is going to be a `CALayer` instance which doesn't have a `strokeColor` property.

You could use a CAShapeLayer but you shouldn't do that just for the stroke since CALayer has `borderColor` property which is probably what you were looking for.

So my advice is to animate the `borderColor` instead.

---

### Not really related to your question:

From the code that you've posted it looks like you are adding the animation inside of your views `drawRect:` implementation. This method should only be used for actual drawing and I strongly suggest that you move the animation code somewhere else. This method will be called every time that your view redraws itself and that is likely too often for adding a new animation.